# DynamoDBMapper Maps support (java)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to write a map using `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save()` and am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: 
Unsupported type: interface java.util.Map for public java.util.Map Config.getAttributes()
```

Is Map not supported by `DynamoDBMapper`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a HashMapMarshaller

```
public class HashMapMarshaller extends JsonMarshaller<HashMap<String, String>> 

{
    @Override
    public String marshall(HashMap<String, String> obj) {
        return super.marshall(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> unmarshall(Class<HashMap<String, String>> clazz, String json) {
        return super.unmarshall(clazz, json);
    }
}
```

And then assign it to your property

```
@DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass=HashMapMarshaller.class)
```